# can woocommerce validate "edit address" the way it validates the checkout?

Tags: validation, edit, woocommerce, account

I am using the woocommerce plugin for wordpress. On the checkout page, you notice there is validation on the client side when the user clicks "place order". However, on the edit my address template, when a user goes to save there address information, there is no validation. How can I duplicate the validation to occur on this template as well?
how to point the validation to the save address template?

Comment: That WooCommerce plugin is using [SmartyStreets](http://smartystreets.com) to validate US addresses. (I work for SmartyStreets.) I'm not familiar with the WooCommerce backend, but maybe you could use [this jQuery plugin](http://smartystreets.com/kb/liveaddress-api/website-forms)? You might also suggest this functionality to the developers of the WooCommerce address validation plugin.

Comment: The validation they are using occurs on the front-end. Most of whats validating seems to live in their assets/js/frontend/checkout.js I want to use this to validate that values are possible for their respective inputs, (not have letters in the phone number input), I do not wish to run a complete validation the way SmartyStreets does

Comment: Are you validating phone numbers or addresses? What do you mean by a "complete validation"? What exactly are you looking for?

Comment: zip, phone, and email seem to be the main issue, the validation makes sure they are in the right format and do not include symbols or characters(phone&zip). this functionality already exists on the checkout page, I just want to include this functionality on the edit my account page

Comment: So your question isn't about the "edit address" function in WooCommerce? You should edit your question to make that clear, that it's about the phone and email instead... I'll remove the street-address tag for you. Incidentally, have you tried contacting Woo support?

Comment: to be clear. It is the Edit Address Template that contains the edit address form which includes the following fields: country, first name, last name, company name, address, town/city, state, zip, email, phone.